# What is the longest manned re-entry from Low Earth Orbit ever recorded?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, reentry, low-earth-orbit, record

What is the record for the longest amount of time that a manned spacecraft has taken to re-enter *from low Earth orbit (LEO)?*

I would prefer the duration between the beginning of the re-entry burn to touchdown, but other endpoints would be acceptable as long as they are specified in the answer.

Comment: “Beginning of the re-entry burn” for the Apollos would be the trans-earth injection burn (or, arguably, a mid-course correction burn), just sayin’...

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Which is exactly why I stated LEO in the title, question body, and tags.

Comment: Aha! My bad....